# How to display an 'either or' option in a setup page?

Tags: dropdown, toggle, options, select, component

Hye guys, we are currently designing a setup process for a web app.

[image]

At this stage, user has to select a type for the system where user needs to switch on either 'Type A' or 'Type B'. It is compulsory for the user to select either one of the options in order to start the system. It is also good to let the user know that if one type is turned on then automatically the other type will be turned off. While 'Modal 1' uses toggle buttons, 'Modal 2' uses a simple dropdown to select options.

The older design we had was A, and we are currently sketching other possible solutions. Would love to hear more from you guys.

Answer (score 2):

#### There's another option: radio buttons.

Since you can only have one type for the system to work, a common control you can use are radio buttons. They are best for 2 -4 options, where the user can quickly scan which configuration they want.

One aspect of this control, is that you can set the **default** option you think is best for most users. You can also educate and explain why if it's relevant.

[image]

#### UPDATE: when there's no default state.

In this case, it's acceptable to have none selected when the user needs to choose. Here's **[Microsoft's guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-radio-buttons?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**:

Don't have a default selection if:

> There is no acceptable default option for safety, security, or legal reasons and therefore the user must make an explicit choice. If the user doesn't make a selection, display an error message to force one.

> The user interface (UI) must reflect the current state and the option hasn't been set yet. A default value would incorrectly imply that the user doesn't need to make a selection.

> The goal is to collect unbiased data. Default values would bias data collection.

You'll also see this pattern in **Google forms**.

The problem with option A, is that you have the appearance of two controls, but in reality there's only one setting. By setting one control, the control below it moves without direct manipulation by the user. *It's hard to tell if it's one setting, or a second setting dependent on the first.*

Your dropdown (option B) keeps options hidden from users.  Better to expose when there's few choices available.

Comment: Thanks Mike, very clean solution. We do have a place for this solution in our setting. However, for the context above, we cannot set the default beforehand and only the user can select between the options.

Comment: @intnnn I've updated my answer. You'll find both Microsoft and Google forms allow for an initial unselected state.